# Front end editor to pending post(for contributors)

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm wanting to create a landing page where new users can come to answer interview questions.  The user will answer the questions that are embedded in the edit area under the normal Wodpress WYSIWYG editor.

Then they can enter a username and password.  Once they click submit the post will go to their newly created user profile area for later editing.

The admin would also be able to publish it from there.  I figure there is no exact plugin for this but I'm curious how easily it can be done.

I've got a form for this now but it doesn't have the WYSIWYG editor and it doesn't allow for users to create a profile at the same time.

I'm basically trying to avoid making the user create a username and password, then have to go to the backend to answer the questions(create content) in the backend.

Having all this on the front end in a landing page would increase conversions/make it easier for users.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Few thoughts that will hopefully get you on the right track:

I do not think that a full implementation of TinyMCE in the frontend is necessary, give the user a textbox or something, if you want WYSIWYG, style that text box as such. Something as basic as answering interview questions can be handled without the overhead of TinyMCE

You can write your own script to allow logged in users (or any users, really) to post to your site. [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) will help you get where you're going on that front.

In regards to creating a profile after answering questions: you can allow anyone to answer, store the data as a cookie if they're not logged in and redirect to the login form (which also allows registration) and then redirect back out (after login/registration) to the final processing form (can all be done from one page, fwiw). If they are logged in, data would get submitted directly.

If you do this right, you will give the user a nice interface to interact with your site through, allow yourself control over the content, keep the users out of the backend (unless they wanna be there), and provide maximal convenience for your users.